# Is it possible to package a WPF app in MSIX format and run OAuth2?

Tags: wpf, oauth-2.0, msix

We have a WPF app that uses OAuth2 to authenticate the user.  We are looking at supporting a MSIX installer but our current OAuth2 flow doesn't work when packaged in MSIX format.  I have been able to get the browser to redirect to the app but the app doesn't receive the authentication code that we need to complete the flow.

I have followed Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/install-parameters#configure-your-application-for-protocol-activation) to register a protocol and I have code in place to handle any parameters.  When we run the flow, the app is restarted without any parameters from the browser.

Is it possible to do this with a WPF app that has been packaged in MSIX format?